# Get access to parent list from R function inside that list

Tags: r, list, types, scope

I have a function which returns a whole series of different bits of data, including data tables, individual numerical values, and plots. I currently have it returning these as a named list. I need one of the items in the list to be a gridExtra multiple plot containing all the other plots.

```
individual_plots=list(ggplot_1,ggplot_2,...ggplot_n);
parent_list<-list(
   irrelevant_num=10,
   ...
   individual_plots=individual_plots,
   single_plot=do.call("grid.arrange",c(individual_plots,ncol=2))
);
return(parent_list);
```

However, it doesn't seem to be possible to save the output of `grid.arrange()` to a variable and render it again later. Instead, it just prints this to the console -

```
parent_list$single_plot

TableGrob (2 x 2) "arrange": 3 grobs
  z     cells    name           grob
1 1 (1-1,1-1) arrange gtable[layout]
2 2 (1-1,2-2) arrange gtable[layout]
3 3 (2-2,1-1) arrange gtable[layout]
```

I thought I could instead have a function to call `grid.arrange()` -

```
individual_plots=list(ggplot_1,ggplot_2,...ggplot_n);
parent_list<-list(
   irrelevant_num=10,
   ...
   individual_plots=individual_plots,
   single_plot=function(){do.call("grid.arrange",c(individual_plots,ncol=2));}
);
return(parent_list);
```

However, of course, this doesn't work because the variable `individual_plots` is no longer in the environment. Instead, I need to be able to refer to `individual_plots` in the list which is the parent of the function.

So my question is - is there a way to refer to the parent list in which a function is stored? Or, is there a better way to pass a gridExtra object as a function result?

Thanks very much in advance for any advice! :)

Comment: Please, provide a minimal reproducible example for us to work on and help you out. Please look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ..... when i wrote a toy example, it worked! :S i really don't know what was wrong with my original code, but the exercise of reproducing the error seems to have given me working code. so, thank you for prompting me to do that!